# How to detect whether code is running in a XBAP application or a WPF application?

Tags: wpf, xbap

Im creating a custom control. I have common code for WPF and XBAP application. I have some different calculation/work to do if it’s a XBAP application. How to detect whether it’s an xbap application or a WPF application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use System.Windows.Interop.BrowserInteropHelper.IsBrowserHosted property identify whether it is hosted on web or windows